# SQL Server: wrap items within group by select

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a stored procedure that contains the following which works fine so far:

```
SELECT      cat, 
            COUNT(*) AS groupCount
FROM        Log_PE 
WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >=
              CONVERT(DATE,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), 112)
                + '01', 112)
GROUP BY    cat
ORDER BY    groupCount desc, cat
FOR XML PATH('ranking'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

**Current XML (example):**

```
<ranking>
  <cat>2</cat>
  <groupCount>84</groupCount>
  <cat>5</cat>
  <groupCount>27</groupCount>
  <cat>9</cat>
  <groupCount>19</groupCount>
</ranking>
```

**Instead I want to get:**

```
<ranking>
  <itemGroup>
      <cat>2</cat>
      <groupCount>84</groupCount>
  </itemGroup>
  <itemGroup>
      <cat>5</cat>
      <groupCount>27</groupCount>
  </itemGroup>
  <itemGroup>
      <cat>9</cat>
      <groupCount>19</groupCount>
  <itemGroup>
</ranking>
```

How can I achieve that each pair of "cat" and "groupCount" gets wrapped separately within an "itemGroup" in the resulting XML string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6873e/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Log_PE
(
  cat int,
  dateEsc datetime
)

insert into Log_PE values(2, '20150227')
insert into Log_PE values(2, '20150227')
insert into Log_PE values(2, '20150227')
insert into Log_PE values(5, '20150227')
insert into Log_PE values(5, '20150227')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select cat,
       count(*) as groupCount
from Log_PE
where dateEsc >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
group by cat
order by groupCount desc, cat
for xml path('itemGroup'), root('ranking'), type
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6873e/1/0)**:

```
<ranking>
  <itemGroup>
    <cat>2</cat>
    <groupCount>3</groupCount>
  </itemGroup>
  <itemGroup>
    <cat>5</cat>
    <groupCount>2</groupCount>
  </itemGroup>
</ranking>
```